# `move` in closure not cloning data

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures

I have closure:

```
move |p| match Params::parse::<Value>(p) {
            Ok(ref v) if v.as_str().is_some() => {
                let chain = v.as_str().unwrap();
                match sender.send(chain) {
                    Ok(_) => futures::done(Ok(Value::Null)).boxed(),
                    Err(err) => futures::failed(JsonRpcError::invalid_params(
                        format!("Node not responding: {}", err.to_string())))
                        .boxed(),
                }
            }
            Ok(_) | Err(_) => {
                futures::failed(JsonRpcError::invalid_params("Invalidlabel"))
                    .boxed()
            }
        };
```

compilation fails with such error:

```
the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<&str>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `[closure@src/rpc/mod.rs:223:13: 237:14 sender:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<&str>]`
```

Isn't `move` keyword should capture and clone `Sender`?

Answer (score 3):

The `move` keyword causes the `Sender` object to **move** into the closure, i.e. it is specifically designed to prevent a borrow from occurring. Your error message indicates that `sender` is not `Sync`, which indicates that a move did not in fact occur. As noted by @red75prim, one way for this to happen is if `sender` is a reference, which will cause it to be copied into the closure, and in turn require the underlying `Sender` object to be `Sync`.

To send an mpsc `Sender` into another thread, you need to first clone it, and then move the clone into the closure:

```
{
    let sender = sender.clone();
    move |p| match Params::parse::<Value>(p) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: A bit missed question, the error said that `Sync` trait not implemented, `clone()` has nothing to deal with it

Comment: @Kostya Krivomaz, are you sure that `sender` isn't a reference? Immutable references are `Copy`, so the reference will be copied into closure, probably causing this error message.

Comment: @red75prim Good catch. In that case, the code in the answer will do the right thing as well, since `clone()` will clone the referenced object.